# Query without where clause - performance tuning - mysql

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have a query such as this

It takes 40 minutes to execute. I cannot add any where clauses as I need all of the data

The configuration of the tables is as follows and below is a snapshot of the explain plan.

I know its an unreasonable query as it accesses every data. But, is there any way I can improve the timings.

```
select 
    pl.CompanyId,
    pl.FarmerCropId,
    ai.ActivityId,
    ai.ActivityName,
    ai.ActivityPlanId,
    ai.ActivityPlanName,
    ai.ActivityScheduleId,
    ai.DAS,
    (case when fca.CompletionDate = '1900-01-01' then null else fca.CompletionDate end)CompletionDate,
    fca.IsClosed,
    fca.LastModifiedDate,
    ai.AttributeDataTypeId,
    ai.AttributeId,
    ai.AttributeName,
    fcaa.FarmerCropActivityAttributeId,
    fcaa.Reading,
    ai.DataTypeId,
    ai.DataTypeName,
    ai.SequenaceNo,
    fca.isactive,
    pl.partitionflag,
    fca.ExpectedStartDate,
    fca.ExpectedClosureDate,
    ai.ActivityMasterIsActive,
    ai.ActivityPlanIsActive,
    ai.ActivityScheduleIsActive,
    ai.AttributeDataTypeIsActive,
    ai.AttributeMasterIsActive,
    case when isclosed = '1' then 'Closed On Time' 
                when isclosed = '2' then 'In Progress' 
                when isclosed = '3' then 'Pending' 
                when isclosed ='5' then 'Late Closed'
                when isclosed ='4' then 'Not Started'  
                end as ClosureStatus  ,
                fca.FarmerCropActivityID
from
activityinformation ai
join FarmerCropActivity fca 
    on ai.activityscheduleid = fca.activityscheduleid 
    and fca.isactive = 1
left join FarmerCropActivityAttributes fcaa 
    on fcaa.farmercropactivityid = fca.farmercropactivityid
    and fcaa.AttributeDataTypeID = ai.AttributeDataTypeID
join plot pl on
pl.farmercropid = fca.farmercropid 
where pl.partitionflag = 1;
```

**activityinformation**

1.Total rows - 137653

2.Indexes -

```
idx_activityinformation_combinedids(ActivityMasterIsActive, ActivityPlanIsActive , ActivityScheduleIsActive,AttributeDataTypeIsActive
 ,AttributeMasterIsActive)
```

3.Columns -

```
source
            ActivityId
            ActivityName
            ActivityPlanId
            ActivityPlanName
            CropTypeId
            ActivityScheduleId
            ActivityintervalDays
            AttributeDataTypeId
            SequenaceNo
            AttributeId
            AttributeName
            DAS
            DataTypeID
            DataTypeName
            talendate
            companyid
            ActivityMasterIsActive
            ActivityPlanIsActive
            ActivityScheduleIsActive
            AttributeDataTypeIsActive
            AttributeMasterIsActive
            Min
            Max
```

**farmercropactivity**

1.Total rows - 2721502

Indexes -

```
idx_fca_activityscheduleid(activityscheduleid), 

idx_fca_activityid(ActivityID),

idx_fca_farmercropid(FarmerCropId),

idx_fca_composite(ActivityScheduleID , IsActive , ActivityID , FarmerCropId , FarmerCropActivityID),

idx_fca_composite1(ActivityScheduleID , IsActive , FarmerCropId , FarmerCropActivityID , ActivityID , CompletionDate , IsClosed ,
 LastModifiedDate , ExpectedStartDate , ExpectedClosureDate)
```

3.Columns -

```
FarmerCropActivityID
            FarmerCropId
            ActivityScheduleID
            CompletionDate
            ExpectedStartDate
            ExpectedClosureDate
            Suggestions
            Comments
            IsClosed
            IsActive
            LastModifiedDate
            LastModifiedBy
            ActivityID
            ActivityReading
            IsMandatory
            ActivityCategoryID
            ClientId
```

**farmercropactivityattributes**

1.Total rows - 4993953

2. Indexes -

   idx_fcaa_farmercropactivityid(FarmerCropActivityID), idx_fcaa_AttributeDataTypeID(AttributeDataTypeID)
3. Columns -

   FarmerCropActivityAttributeID
   FarmerCropActivityID
   AttributeDataTypeID
   Reading
   ClientId

**plot**

1.Total rows - where partitionflag = 1 --- 328838

2.indexes -

```
idx_composite2(companyid , partitionflag , FarmerCropId)
```

3.Columns -

```
 source
            companyid
            Company
            FarmerId
            FarmerCode
            FarmerName
            LandId
            PlotName
            Latitude
            Longitude
            FarmerCropId
            Village
            DistrictId
            CropId
            crop
            VarietyId
            Variety
            SowingDate
            SowingWeek
            SowingWeekRange
            SowingMonth
            SowingMonthName
            SowingYear
            DeclaredArea
            AuditedArea
            SowingArea
            IsAudited
            IsGeoTagged
            ExpectedHarvestPerAcre
            FirstExpectedHarvestDate
            FirstActualHarvestDate
            HarvestArrivalStatus
            PlannedQuantity
            ExpectedQuantity
            CurrentQuantity
            HarvestQuantity
            RegistrationDate
            RegistrationWeek
            RegistrationWeekRange
            RegistrationMonth
            RegistrationMonthName
            RegistrationYear
            ActivityPlanId
            ActivityPlanName
            HarvestPlanId
            HarvestPlanName
            LastModifiedDate
            Address
            Territory
            Taluka
            ReestimateDate
            NewHarvestDate
            NewHarvestQuantity
            ReestimateReasonCode
            ReestimateReason
            Comments
            FarmerCropHarvestreestimateId
            IsReestimated
            ReestimateDaysShift
            CurrentQuantityWithoutReestimate
            HarvestUnitId
            harvestunit
            ExtendedHarvestUnitId
            ExtendedHarvestUnit
            ConversionFactor
            MobileNumber
            Coordinates
            PreferredSKUTypeId
            PreferredSKUName
            Capacity
            Soiltypeid
            soildesc
            Irrigationtypeid
            irrigationtypedesc
            lastmodifiedon
            partitionflag
            areaunitid
            areaunitname
            archivedate
            talendate
            geoid
            idtoroot
            nametoroot
            RevisedFirstExpectedHarvestDate
            HarvestStatusId
            HarvestStatus
```

[image]

Thanks
Rathi

Comment: You can send less data. That's about it. You're sending ~136k rows. It takes a while to send that, and for the other side to accept / parse it. What you are asking is to optimize the part where you *find* those 136k - but that's only 1/3 of your peformance problems and as you can see - the part of finding rows to join is quite fast.

Comment: What is your query?

Comment: Apologies!! had missed the query, have included it now in the main question

Comment: It's potentially 136K * 92 * 1 * 3 rows !

Answer (score 0):

Needed:

```
fcaa: INDEX(FarmerCropActivityID, AttributeDataTypeID, Reading)
```

(`Reading` must be last; the ordering of the other two is optional.)  This is better than the two single-column indexes you have, and it is "covering".

```
plot: INDEX(partitionflag , FarmerCropId, companyid)
```

`companyid` must be *last*, not first.  Again, this is better than what you have, and it is 'covering'.  Add this index.  And remove the existing one -- but only if it is not needed by some other query.